# How to plot value counts for each subset in matplotlib/seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am relatively new to matplotlib and there is probably a better way to deal with the problem. I have tried `sns.countplot()`, which does not have sorting option. So I tried to do it with a bar plot and pandas for counting:

```py
my_data = pd.DataFrame({'actions': ['buy','buy','buy','observe','consult'] , 'places':['NY','AR','AR','NY','AR']})
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (5,7))
axs = axs.ravel()
for place in my_data['places']: 
    x = 0 
    temp_df = my_data[my_data['places'] == place]
    axs[x] = sns.barplot(y=temp_df.actions.value_counts().index, x=temp_df.actions.value_counts().values, color="#43B8E7",orient = 'h')
    axs[x].set_title(place)
    x=+1
```

where data look like

```
   actions places
0      buy     NY
1      buy     AR
2      buy     AR
3  observe     NY
4  consult     AR
```

and the code produces what's below. As you may have assumed, I need to plot NY as well, however, because of subsetting or something missed in the loop it does not work well. How to fix that? I feel that this is the easy one, however, cannot find it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
(my_data.groupby('places')['actions']
    .value_counts().unstack('places')
    .plot.bar(subplots=True)
)
```

Or similarly:

```
(pd.crosstab(my_data['actions'], my_data['places'])
    .plot.bar(subplots=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]

---

If you want horizontal bars:

```
(pd.crosstab(my_data['actions'], my_data['places'])
    .plot.barh(subplots=True, layout=[1,2])
)
```

Output:

[image]

---

Or we can fix your code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (5,7))
axs = axs.ravel()
for ax,place in zip(axs,my_data['places'].unique()): 
    temp_df = my_data[my_data['places'] == place].actions.value_counts()
    sns.barplot(y=temp_df.index, x=temp_df, 
                color="#43B8E7", ax=ax, orient = 'h')
    ax.set_title(place)
```

Output (which isn't very well-aligned IMHO):

[image]

Comment: Use `seaborn.FacetGrid.map` in place of your for-loop

Comment: @PaulH I had difficluty understanding how to use Facet here since I have to count objects. I think groupby would make the trick but in general for-loop is behind FacetGrid, so it's okayyy. Reinventing the wheel here :)

Comment: @simplymaxim you'd `map` your countplot (which *can* sort objects) on the grid

Answer (score 1):

I would use a facetgrid since you're already using seaborn:

```py
import pandas
import seaborn

axgrid = pandas.DataFrame({
    'actions': ['buy','buy','buy','observe','consult'] ,
    'places':['NY','AR','AR','NY','AR']
}).pipe((seaborn.catplot, 'data'), 
        y="actions", col="places",
        order=['buy', 'consult', 'observe'],
        kind="count"
)
```

[image]

And you get:

Comment: have not used pipe before. Thank you! Will explore